# Ubuntu 18.04 wmctrl issues

Tags: shortcut-keys, wmctrl

So I've just upgraded to 18.04 and have been adjusting settings and such but am having issues with wmctrl.
I had a shortcut set for toggling a window to be always on top "wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b toggle,above" but after updating I can't toggle or remove this through wmctrl. It sets to be on top but not back to normal after, any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: Just in case, `wmctrl` won't play nice with Wayland. Run `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` to check. For more on what won't work in Wayland look at https://askubuntu.com/a/1111348/248158

Comment: Any luck on this? Most answers I have found are saying it's simple a conflict with Wayland, but unfortunately this is not the case for me. I am currently running on X11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually. I dug a bit more into this and found a solution. It can be found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/bozho3/i_use_always_on_top_shortkey_problem_is_how_to/). This uses built in functionality so `wmctrl` is not needed. It does use a GUId configuration editor but I actually find this tool to be quite handy. Just be careful not to edit things that you are not sure what they do. It could be fatal to some applications or your system.

Just in case the link ever breaks or future readers do not wish to follow the link:

1. Install dconf-editor with `sudo apt install dconf-editor`
2. Run `dconf-editor` to open the settings editor.
3. Navigate to: `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings`
4. Select `toggle-above`, note there is also an option for `always-on-top` this did not work for me
5. Toggle of `Use default value`
6. Set custom value. Must be an array containing a string. I set mine to `['<Shift><Alt>a']`
7. Save by clicking the check mark in the bottom left