# What is the equivalent of xkill on wayland?

Tags: wayland, xkill

Xkill is a utility program distributed with the X Window System that instructs the X server to forcefully terminate its connection to a client, thus "killing" the client.[1] When run with no command line arguments, the program displays a special cursor (usually a crosshair or a skull and crossbones) and displays a message such as

```
Select the window whose client you wish to kill with button 1 ...
```

If a non-root window is then selected, the server will close its connection to the client that created that window, and the window will be destroyed.

I would like to achieve the same behavior for wayland windows, if possible.

PS: I am on Kubuntu 21.10 running a wayland session, but would prefer something DE agnostic.

Comment: Very likely, there may not be (yet) a similar utility. See for the "why" here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111346/why-cant-i-kill-a-terminal-window-with-xkill-in-wayland?rq=1

Comment: @vanadium Thank you, the bug reports in particular are interesting. I am well aware that xkill could not work on wayland and that porting it would actually be writing a new application. I am just wondering if there is a similar utility.

Answer (score 4):

KDE has a built-in function that provides this.
Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> and then click on a window or press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to cancel

Comment: Does this work for you on wayland? I thought it actually just calls xkill (In anycase it does not work on a wayland session for me)

Comment: It does work for me on Wayland. It might be a different Key combination for you for some reason. Try CTRL+META+ESC. If that doesn't work, then try going into System Settings -> Shortcuts -> KWin and search for Kill Window. 
If you still can't find it or it doesn't work can you tell me which version of KDE Plasma you have?
And if you do find it and it works can you tell me, so I can update my answer?

Comment: I use Plasma 5.24.6. Ctr. + Meta +Esc does not kill wayland windows on my system. Are you sure the windows you are killing under wayland are not actually xwayland windows?

Comment: I can kill Wayland and XWayland windows. Your KDE version should support it though... Have you looked into the Settings, if you or kubuntu may have bound Ctrl + Meta + Esc to xkill rather than the KDE one?

Comment: I am going to check on the WE. (I am on xorg on my work machine due to using nvidia and a displaylink driver, and because on KDE wayland still is not a full citizen)